# change update speed without changing loop speed?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Could someone explain me how to change my hero animation without changing setTimeout. i Mean how to make hero animate slower than all canvas. by animate i mean changing frames

```
function draw() {
if (hero.ready){
    ctx.clearRect (0 , 0, 500 , 500 );
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 )";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = -10;
    ctx.drawImage(image[hero.image],hero.frames * hero.sizeX, 0, hero.sizeX, hero.sizeY, hero.posX, hero.posY, hero.sizeX, hero.sizeY);
}
hero.frames++;
if (hero.frames >= 2) hero.frames = 0;
setTimeout( draw, 1000 / 5 );
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Myrez/tEY6x/) full example.

Comment: what about the animation do you want to change ? i don't see how you expect to change the update speed without changing the `setTimeout` interval - that **is** the update speed, right?

Comment: how to make hero animate slower than all canvas

Comment: Animations need to adhere to frame rates. If your canvas updates 60 times per second, and the animation has 30 frames, it would show one frame every other frame.

Comment: ye i know i want to achieve canvas 60 fps but animation with few frames to be a lot slower. so it would look normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify on the concept of 'delta time', if you were to simply increment a counter without scaling it against real time, it would increment as fast as `draw` is called. However by scaling it, you are guaranteed a certain amount of frames per second. This way, you can always be sure that your animation is as slow or as fast as you want it. You can set your threshold to be for example 500 milliseconds (one frame every half a second), and so on.

```
var counter = 0;
function draw() {
  // deltaTime is how you plan on counting real seconds
  // against your frame ticks
  counter += deltaTime;

...

// threshold would be your delay
if (counter >= threshold)
{
  hero.frames++;
  if (hero.frames >= 2) hero.frames = 0;
  counter = 0;
}

}

setInterval( draw, 1000 / 5 );
```